# How to get screen lock/unlock events on the iPhone when app is suspended?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a requirement where i need to track the iphone device state like if device is locked or unlocked. I was able to track these events when the app is running in foreground or background. But i also need to track the same when the app is suspended. Something like tracking the user location in background when the app is suspended. But i don't need to track the user location but only the device state.

Please suggest me some steps to solve this issue in objective-c.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform any operations once your app is in suspended state and you can not prevent your app from getting suspended unless you are using one of the background capability mode mentioned in this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

So what you are looking for is not possible if you are not using either of background modes allowed by apple.

**EDIT**

Even if you go on and enable one of background mode like background audio, your app is likely to be rejected during review process as reviewer will see you do not have a valid reason to use that particular background mode.

Comment: so, it is possible if i enable background modes like background fetch? if so can you please guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Background fetch will also not keep your active permanently, it is being called by OS at a regular interval of time.

Comment: @user3584797 : I added some more info about why cant you use a background mode if you dont have any functionality that actually needs it

Comment: Thanks for the edit... but if i use Background fetch, OS will invoke the app at regular intervals of time right. So, in that case can I get the required details about the device state?

Comment: Yes you should be able to, but background fetch is for purpose of downloading newer data from server so that app could show newer content when user opens the app without any delay. So again you might face chances of rejection but it could work. Also you have no control over when background fetch is done.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. So, in the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions i had set the setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval to 2.0 and in performFetchWithCompletionHandler method i wrote the code to get the device screen status. so, i want to make sure how this works? can you please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116683/discussion-between-bhumit-mehta-and-user3584797).